# Length of Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney if it were a novel?

Tags: phoenix-wright-ace-attorney

How long would Phoenix Wright be if you consolidated all of the text and dialogue into a book?

Comment: Number of words? number of pages? that's going to vary depending if you mean trade paperback or mass market paperback, font size, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a video game issue, but about determining the length of a theoretical book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this list](https://gamicus.gamepedia.com/List_of_longest_video_game_scripts) Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney consists of some 210,000 words in the English version, spread over around 80,000 lines of text. For comparison's sake that's longer than Dune at 185,723 words, though shorter than War and Peace at 561,304 words. Almost three times as long as Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone (77,000 words).

Of course, that's just looking at the raw text. Much of that wouldn't make much sense unedited in a book, as it's almost all dialogue (or descriptions). If you were to try and make it into a novel, whilst retaining all the text, you would need to add text describing what was happening. (As an example, in game you can click on a ladder and Phoenix will say something like "It looks like a ladder." Maya: "No, Phoenix, that's a stepladder!" Phoenix: "Is there a difference?" In a novel you'd need some text describing that he was looking at a ladder, and which characters were talking.)